# Simple batch file only fails when called from nmake.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, nmake

I have a simple batch file `foo.bat`:

```c
@ECHO OFF

setlocal

echo %PATH%

WHERE /Q wsl.exe
if %ERRORLEVEL%% NEQ 0 (
echo No find wsl.exe %ERRORLEVEL%
exit /B
)
```

When I just run it in cmd or explicitly with `cmd.exe /C foo.bat` I have no problems. But if I put it into a **nmake.exe** `Makefile`:

```
all:
        call foo.bat

.PHONY : all
```

and call it with `nmake.exe /f Makefile all` it will fail:

```c
C:\cmder_mini\bin;C:\cmder_mini\vendor\bin;C:\cmder_mini\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts;C:\cmder_mini\vendor\conemu-maximus5;C:\cmder_mini\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;E:\VisualStudio\Common7\IDE\\Extensions\Microsoft\IntelliCode\CLI;E:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x86;E:\VisualStudio\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;E:\VisualStudio\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;E:\VisualStudio\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;E:\VisualStudio\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;E:\VisualStudio\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\\x86;E:\VisualStudio\\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;E:\VisualStudio\Common7\IDE\;E:\VisualStudio\Common7\Tools\;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python310\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;E:\home\nat\mulle-clang-project\13.0.0.1\bin;C:\Users\nat\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;E:\VisualStudio\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;E:\VisualStudio\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;E:\VisualStudio\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\cmder_mini
No find wsl.exe  1
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'call' : return code '0x1'
```

When I diff the output of the working script and the failing nmake run I get

```
1,5d0
<
< Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.30.30709.0
< Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
<
<       call foo.bat
7,9d1
< No find wsl.exe  1
< NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'call' : return code '0x1'
< Stop.
```

So the PATH is identical. Once it finds "wsl.exe" in PATH and once it doesn't ? I have no clue here...

Comment: If you compare the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`  environment variable, you'll see the difference.  nmake is launching a 32-bit cmd process, which will have `\windows\system32` redirected to `syswow64`, which won't have wsl.exe.  Since `wsl.exe` is 64-bit only, there's no way to run it directly.  You may have a `wsl.bat` in your path somewhere, but that will likely launch a new console.

Comment: Please read first the Microsoft documentation pages [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details) and[File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector). Then use in your batch file following lines: 1.`@echo off`, 2. `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion`, 3. `if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\wsl.exe (set "SystemPath=%SystemRoot%\System32") else set "SystemPath=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative"`, ...

Comment: ... 4. `if not exist %SystemPath%\wsl.exe echo ERROR: Could not find wsl.exe!& exit /B 1`, 5. `echo Found wsl.exe in %SystemPath%` or use `%SystemPath%\wsl.exe` for whatever purpose and finally as last line `endlocal`.

Comment: Perhaps `if %ERRORLEVEL%% NEQ 0 ` should be `if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ` (`%` is doubled...

Comment: Thanks AC for the explanation and Mofi for the proper solution to my problem. I wouldn't have figured this out on my own I think.